# how to fix disk partition corruption or mount the disk

Tags: linux, boot, filesystems, grub, arch-linux

Hi I hope you're doing fine i have a big problem in my disk or system It start when **I decide to boot windows on Flash disk (usb adata drive)**

so I've used the tool **"WOEUSB"**
https://github.com/slacka/WoeUSB

And I've choose to boot the flash drive with the **"-d"** flag (**means all the disk will be bootable not just a partition**)

when the process end , I've reboot the PC then I was surprised by the **GRUB rescue interface** showed up :

[Grub Rescue Interface Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/br3lz.jpg)

So I've tried to make the rescue steps (set the prefix "boot" and root to the GRUB insmod .. )

**So everything was set without problems**

So for example when I tap in the grub shell

`ls (hd0,msdos3)/ or ls /`

This the result :

[The result of the last commands in grub shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZRzet.jpg)

also when I tap

`ls /home/username/`

all my files is showed up without problem

[The result of the last command in GRUB Shell](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z7BOr.jpg)

when I reboot , It returned me to the grub rescue interface again

So I decided to boot **Linux mint** into **USB drive** and boot it in live boot

and try to mount the disk by the mount command

`sudo mount /dev/nvme0n1p3 /media/`

**(I have NVME hard disk)**

and this error showed up

`mount: /media: wrong fs type, bad option, bad superblock on /dev/nvme0n1p3, missing codepage or helper program, or other error.`

I've tried to fix disk with **fsck** and this is the result

```
sudo fsck /dev/nvme0n1p3 
fsck from util-linux 2.34
e2fsck 1.45.5 (07-Jan-2020)
The filesystem size (according to the superblock) is 120781142 blocks
The physical size of the device is 107741184 blocks
Either the superblock or the partition table is likely to be corrupt!
Abort<y>? no
/dev/nvme0n1p3 contains a file system with errors, check forced.
Pass 1: Checking inodes, blocks, and sizes
Inode 8522540 extent tree (at level 1) could be shorter.  Optimize<y>? no
Inode 8663080 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize<y>? no
Inode 12326736 extent tree (at level 1) could be narrower.  Optimize<y>? no
Inode 15729563 extent tree (at level 2) could be narrower.  Optimize<y>? no
Error reading block 108003360 (Invalid argument) while getting next inode from scan.  Ignore error<y>? no
Error while scanning inodes (26885355): Can't read next inode
e2fsck: aborted
```

So the big Question is :

**1-How can I read or mount my disk  [command (or python script or C program)]**

**2-What is the cause that make the disk corrupted**

**3-Why GRUB can list my files and read it , and the other shells cannot do that?**

**-------!! I cannot format the disk because I really need to restore my files ----------**

Comment: I cannot format the disk because I really need to restore my files ----------    ::::   You probably should have thought of this first.  Windows to Go on a flash drive was dumped by Microsoft (too slow).  Windows creates its own partitions including UEFI outside of dual boot. Start with Linux boot disk, save your data and start again properly.